# Sports Matches Schedule API/SDK

Tags: web-services, sport

Can anyone suggest some good free or paid SDKs/APIs in PHP for "Sports Matches Schedule?  The API should cover most of the famous sports.

**Update 1**

e.g.,
  Take Tennis, then the API should give me the schedules of Grand slam Matches Schedules per week/day.

**Update 2**
As suggested by Mawg,

```
I want to access official fixtures like Wimbledon, RG, Cricket matches around the world etc.
```

Comment: Why negative vote?

Comment: I can’t speak for the downvoter, but your question lacks details. You have to describe what you are looking for exactly (and what features it needs to have), ideally also how you intend to use it, and what "good" means to you.

Comment: I upvoted, to cancel that downvote, aftre you updated. But you are still not  making it clear if you want to schedule matches yoursefl, or to see major sporting fiixtures which were scheduled by others (I suspect the latter).

Comment: @Mawg, Thanks. I do not want to build myself. I need API/Webservices. I do not know now how I add more information. It is a straight forward question. Anything which related to this functionalities is welcome.

Comment: What I am asking is - do you want to add matches,? E.g for your local tennis club? Or do you *only* want to access official fixtures, such as Wimbeldon, Olympics, World cup, etc?

Comment: Thanks  for direction.  I want to  access official fixtures. Great.

Comment: What permissions do you need on the data? Permission to read for just yourself? Permission to show the data to others for free? Permission to show the data to your paying customers? Permission to redistribute the data to other companies? And what is your yearly budget?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, budget is not finalized yet. The permissions would be to read the data and display on the website. Something like  `http://www.skysports.com/watch/football-on-sky`

Answer (score 1):

Wikidata offers an API giving sport results for very important competitions.

You have to write the query for each competition. The query syntax and data format might change depending on the sport and event.

For instance, here is the query for the results of EURO 2016 soccer games:

[Wikidata query for EURO 2016](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20v%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20pq%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FmatchNR%29%20AS%20%3FmatchNR%29%20%3Fmatch%20%3FmatchLabel%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fpit%29%20AS%20%3Fday%29%20%28CONCAT%28%3FteamNameA%2C%22%20vs.%20%22%2C%3FteamNameB%29%20AS%20%3Fteams%29%20%28CONCAT%28STR%28SAMPLE%28%3FscoreA%29%29%2C%22%3A%22%2CSTR%28SAMPLE%28%3FscoreB%29%29%29%20AS%20%3Fscore%29%20%28SUBSTR%28SAMPLE%28%3Fstage%29%2C16%2C100%29%20AS%20%3Fstage%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FwinnerName%29%20AS%20%3Fwinner%29%20%3FrefereeLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fmatch%20wdt%3AP361%20%3Fpartof%20.%20%3Fpartof%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fstage%20.%20FILTER%28lang%28%3Fstage%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%3Fmatch%20p%3AP179%20%3FmatchSeries%20.%20%3FmatchSeries%20v%3AP179%20wd%3AQ189571%20.%20%3FmatchSeries%20pq%3AP1545%20%3FmatchNR%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fmatch%20wdt%3AP585%20%3Fpit%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fmatch%20wdt%3AP1346%20%3Fwinner%20.%20%3Fwinner%20wdt%3AP1532%20%3FwCountry%20.%20%3FwCountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FwinnerName%20.%20FILTER%28lang%28%3FwinnerName%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fmatch%20wdt%3AP1652%20%3Freferee%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmatch%20p%3AP1923%20%3FteamAStatement%20.%20%3FteamAStatement%20v%3AP1923%20%3FteamA%20.%20%3FteamAStatement%20pq%3AP794%20wd%3AQ24633211%20.%20OPTIONAL%7B%3FteamAStatement%20pq%3AP1351%20%3FscoreA%7D%20.%20%3FteamA%20wdt%3AP1532%20%3FCountryA%20.%20%3FCountryA%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FteamNameA%20.%20FILTER%28lang%28%3FteamNameA%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fmatch%20p%3AP1923%20%3FteamBStatement%20.%20%3FteamBStatement%20v%3AP1923%20%3FteamB%20.%20%3FteamBStatement%20pq%3AP794%20wd%3AQ24633216%20.%20OPTIONAL%7B%3FteamBStatement%20pq%3AP1351%20%3FscoreB%7D%20.%20%3FteamB%20wdt%3AP1532%20%3FCountryB%20.%20%3FCountryB%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FteamNameB%20.%20FILTER%28lang%28%3FteamNameB%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cde%22%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fmatch%20%3FmatchLabel%20%3FteamNameA%20%3FteamNameB%20%3Freferee%20%3FrefereeLabel%0AORDER%20BY%20ASC%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3FmatchNR%29%29)

[image: Wikidata sports results EURO 2016 open data query]

For other sports/competition, browse from https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Category:Sports_WikiProjects

Disadvantages:

- Not a lot of data available. Your local or even national tennis competitions might not be covered.

Advantages:

- The data is freely reusable and redistributable, even for commercial purposes.

Comment: Will be very useful.